# Creating a big compile time map using boost::hana

Tags: c++, c++17, boost-hana

I'm trying to use `boost::hana` to create a `constexpr` lookup table that gets quite big (up to 32768 elements). This is my code:

```
#include <boost/hana.hpp>
#include <boost/hana/assert.hpp>

namespace hana = boost::hana;

template <typename Count>
static constexpr auto createLookupTable(void)
{
    auto indices = hana::make_range(hana::int_c<0>, hana::int_c<Count::value>);

    return hana::unpack(indices, [](auto... index)
    {
        return hana::make_map(
            hana::make_pair(
                index,
                hana::int_c<0>)...);
    });
}

int main()
{
    constexpr auto lookupTable = createLookupTable<std::integral_constant<unsigned, 128>>();
    BOOST_HANA_CONSTANT_CHECK(hana::length(lookupTable) == hana::size_c<128>);
}
```

For testing purpose the value of each pair is `hana::int_c<0>`. This gets replaced by something meaningful.
It takes some time to compile this. Is there a faster way to do it using hana?

Thanks

Comment: Wait, I'm nut fluent in `hana`: are your indexes contiguous from `0` to `Count::value`?

Comment: @YSC correct. I know going up to 32768 is much but I wanted to see whether it works since these lookups are predestinated for getting created at compile time.

Comment: @Wum, hey I wonder how to slice at runtime with an int?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maps are the right tool to represent a lookup table when you deal with sparse indexes or when there is no order on the keys.

Since you're dealing with contiguous integers as your lookup table keys, you really should stick to old C-style arrays, or better yet, `std::array<128, your_value_type>`:

```
constexpr std::array<128, your_value_type> lookupTable = {
    // ...
};
```

Once you've got this, you can delegate the construction of that table to a `constexpr` templated function:

```
template<unsigned size>
constexpr std::array<size, your_value_type> lookupTable()
{
    return /* ... */;
}
constexpr auto lookupTable = lookupTable<128>();
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to implement it using std::array.

Answer (score 0):

> It tooks some time to compile this. Is there a faster way to do it?

I don't think it is specific to [`hana`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/hana/doc/html/index.html) (which I don't know and that I am discovering). Compilation of templated C++ code is complex and slow, and takes some time (since C++ [template expansion is Turing complete](http://cpptruths.blogspot.fr/2005/11/c-templates-are-turing-complete.html), it could take an arbitrary large time).

Compilation of templated code has significantly improved in recent versions of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) and of Clang, so use a recent version (e.g. [GCC 8](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-8/) in may 2018) if you can.

In practice (if you can afford that), I would recommend initializing a large array of POD `struct`s or in your case an array of integers at compile time, perhaps by having a generated C++ (or even C) file it, and at initialization (so at runtime) convert that array into your `hana`

Otherwise, leave your `hana` template initialization in some separate file, and accept that it takes a lot of time to compile (but at runtime it would run very quickly). Perhaps [ccache](https://ccache.samba.org/) could be useful.